# How to Increase ZipSecureFile EntrySize greater than 4294967295L(4gb)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to parse 250 MB xlsx file and convert it to csv. I am using the source from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java.
While parsing i am getting following error:

> Zip bomb detected! The file would exceed the max size of the expanded data in the zip-file. This may indicates that the file is used to inflate memory usage and thus could pose a security risk. You can adjust this limit via ZipSecureFile.setMaxEntrySize() if you need to work with files which are very large. Counter: 4294968058, cis.counter: 188252160Limits: MAX_ENTRY_SIZE: 4294967295.

So i need to setMaxEntrySize which is greater than 4GB to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try setting a size of `-1` ?

Comment: Currently Apache POI does not allow more than 4G, setMaxEntrySize() fails on maxEntrySize < 0 || maxEntrySize > 0xFFFFFFFFL, not sure why exactly, but currently you probably need to build Apache POI with some changes to make it work for larger files.